# How do I keep the context without changing the structure of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, this

How I can keep the context and getting true data from ajax response, adhering to current structure of my code?

For example:
In the second case, I get the correct data. 
How do I get the same result using the current structure? (first console.log)

```js
var options = {
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value'
};

function getJson(options) {
    this.init(options);
}

$.extend(getJson.prototype, {
    options: null,

    init: function (options) {
        this.options = options;

        return $.get(this.options.url);
    }
});

console.log('First:');
console.log(new getJson(options.url));
console.log('Second:');
console.log($.get(options.url));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to accomplish? What is shown is a lot of code for a very simple `$.getJSON()` call. Also, no matter what you do you need to account for ajax being asynchronous.

Comment: @charlietfl, This is a simple abstract example. It is more important for me to understand how to get the correct values ​​with my structure without losing context.

Comment: So that brings up question about higher level objective. You could turn what you have now into a simple factory function quite easily with no real need to worry about context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use your code. You need to pass only `options` to `getJson`, not `options.url`.

Your `init` function returns a promise, so you can use `.then` and `.done` to work with the result.

```js
var options = {
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
};

function getJson(options) {
    return this.init(options);
}

$.extend(getJson.prototype, {
    options: null,

    init: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        return $.get(this.options.url);
    }
});

$.when( new getJson(options) )
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .fail(function(data, statusText) {
    console.log(statusText)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I will try. For processing I use $.when, .done, .fail.